# Draggable panel in android

Tags: android, panel, draggable

In Youtube app, when you watch a video, you can drag it to move, zoomout, maximine or close it by swipe to right/left.I want to create such application in android

Comment: Can we see code which you are trying? which helps you get idea.

Comment: @https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel in this i tried draggable view

Comment: I tried this example in that my problem is when i am click listview item in draggable panel i want to display another draggable view like youtube

Comment: help me out from here